# Using AngularJS and IE11, image not updating upon updating the ng-src attribute of the image tag

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I am using angularJS to change profilepics of users in my application. When a user uploads a new profile pic, I set the ng-src of the user's image tag to the updated URL that I receive from the backend. This works fine in chrome, firefox, but when it comes to IE11, the src gets updated using angular but the image does not show. IE shows it as a broken image link.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Could someone help me out here?

EDIT:
I have to right click on the small black 'X' and then select 'Show Image', then the correct image displays.

EDIT:
Below is my code

```
<img ng-src="{{profilePic}}">
```

Comment: have you got any angular code to show what you're doing?